# Import S/MIME certificate (*.p12) in thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

I'm not able to import a S/MIME certificate in Thunderbird. The file format is *.p12. All instructions I found guide me to the "setting > advanced" where I should open the certificates tab. But this tab is not shown in my setting (see screen).

System:

- Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
- Thunderbird 52.8.0 (64bit)

[image: Screenshot Setting]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tab is there but the theme of your Thunderbird installation doesn't highlight the tabs properly:

[image: Manually highlighted Certificates tab]

Compare with my Thunderbird installation which highlights tabs properly:

[image: Properly highlighting Thunderbird theme]